# Can I create a custom web-level site definition for use in a Publishing Portal site collection?

Tags: sharepoint, site-definition

I originally created a site collection based on the "Publishing Portal" site definition. Now some time later I'd like to create my own site definition at the web scope level for certain subwebs. The problem is that my custom site definition is not showing up in the list of options, only "Publishing Site with Workflow" appears.

I'm pretty sure I've tracked this down to the site definition file for the Publishing Portal site definition (located at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates\BLANKINTERNET\XML\onet.xml). It contains the following line:

```
<Property Key="AvailableWebTemplates" Value="*-BLANKINTERNET#2"/>
```

Configuration #2 of the BLANKINTERNET Template definition happens to be Publishing Site with Workflow.

Are there any solutions that will display my custom web-level site definition that do not require recreating the site collection with a new site definition?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your site template is available to be used in subsites by clicking on Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Page Layouts and Site Templates (under the Look and Feel category).

From there if you choose the option "Subsites can only use the following site templates" see if your template is listed and make it available if possible. It should then appear in the selection.

If that doesn't work let me know mate as there is another solution to this which I can look up.

Cheers

Comment: Forgot to mention in the question that I tried that. It's not showing anywhere! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the Webtemp.*.xml make sure that the Template configuration tag has the attribute set to

```
SubWebOnly="True" 
and 
RootWebOnly="False"
```